# How do I replace the virtio_net driver?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I have a modified virtio_net driver compiled out of tree (with netmap driver).  I added it to the proper /lib/modules tree and ran depmod but the kernel does not use my module at boot time.  There are duplicate modules but supposedly I have instructed depmod to give priority to mine.  The lsmod command shows virtio_net being loaded but it is not my virtio_net.

Bizarrely, moving the standard virtio_net module out of /lib/modules results in the same behavior -- virtio_net is supposedly loaded (according to lsmod) but it is definitely not the module under /lib/modules.

lspci -k says that the driver loaded for the network interface in question is virtio-pci.  Is that the issue here, another driver is really being used but it is claiming that it is virtio_net?

I can rmmod virtio_net and modprobe virtio_net after boot and all is well, but I would like to get the system to load my module automatically.

Comment: Since stackoverflow.com is for programming and this question is not programming related, I think this should be moved over to unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: thanks for the polite admonition I will do so